# Using column values from one table within a select clause from another table

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle table called: **col_mapping** where a column in this table has the column values of columns from another table.

Example data of table: col_mapping

```
    ID    DESCR     COL_VALS
------------------------------
    1     LABEL     COL_1
    2     NAME_ADDR COL_2:COL_3
    3     SALARY    COL4
```

Based on the above table, I now would like to go through each record in col_mapping and use the COL_VALS as part of my

```
select COL_VALS from other_tab
```

obviously, where there is more than one value like **COL_2:COL_3**, need to replace the ':' with a ','

```
    SELECT COL_1 from other_tab;
    SELECT COL_2,COL_3 from other_tab;
    SELECT COL_4 from other_tab;
```

Comment: Do you just want to generate those select statements as strings, or actually execute them? To execute them you would need some form of dynamic SQL; and what would you do with the results of the queries? Also, is the `descr` column relevant - is that supposed to be an alias for the queried columns, and if so is the second one supposed to combine `col_2` and `col_3` into a single value?

Comment: @Alex Poole I would actually like to generate those select statements and place the actual values for those columns within the other_tab table into a staging  table. The descr column simply let me know what lives in the col_vals so with col_2 and col_3, I actually want these as separate values. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Does your staging table have the same column names and data types as `other_tab`? if not how are you mapping and converting the values?

Comment: @Alex Poole - staging table will be the same as other_tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate and execute insert statements based on the `col_vals` value using dynamic SQL, inside a cursor loop over the `col_mappings` rows:

```
begin
  for r in (select replace(col_vals, ':', ',') as cols from col_mapping) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('insert into staging_tab(' || r.cols || ')'
      || ' select ' || r.cols || ' from other_tab');
    execute immediate 'insert into staging_tab(' || r.cols || ')'
      || ' select ' || r.cols || ' from other_tab';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

The cursor just gets the `cols_val` value, replacing colon with comma. The generated insert uses that modified `cols_val` as both the insert column list and the select list - since you said the staging table will match the `other_tab` structure.

The `dbms_output` line is just so you can see the generated statements - it ins't necessary for the code to run, and you'll need to `set serveroutput on` or equivalent to see it anyway. With that enabled, running that block using your example mapping data shows:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

insert into staging_tab(COL_1) select COL_1 from other_tab
insert into staging_tab(COL_2,COL_3) select COL_2,COL_3 from other_tab
insert into staging_tab(COL4) select COL4 from other_tab
```

What you'll end up with is the data from each row in `other_tab` spread across multiple rows in `staging_tab`, with lots of null values. Hopefully that's what you intended.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole - will take a look and let you know.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole - all looks good but I've had to create a new thread as I now need to include the COL_VALS in a where condition.